# ClaimCenter : MainContact value doesn't persist when the Insured is company and reporter is a person during FNOL wizard

Tags: guidewire

In Basic Info wizard screen, the main contact value is not persisting when click on NEXT step and click on BACK step , the main contact value is switching as "Different Person". This happens when Insured is some company and Reporter is a person .

If we select Same as Reporter Under Main Contact and click on NEXT and again come back with BACK button . It is switching to Different Person under Main Contact. Much appreciated for any help ?

Comment: could you please share a screenshot of your development? and is the field is part of any entity?

Comment: Could you give more information, screenshots, or pieces of code?

Comment: Thanks Shivanandam & Lopez . I got the solution finally for this.

Comment: It would be informative to know what the actual problem and the solution found was.